# MySQL Query Returning Empty

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables - posts and postmeta.

```
posts
ID   title   category  post_status  post_type    

1    ABC      cat-1    Publish      Store
2    DEF      cat-2    Publish      Store
3    GHI      cat-3    Publish      Store
4    JKL      cat-2    Publish      Store
5    XYZ      cat-5    Draft        Store
6    MNO      cat-9    Publish      Article
```

and

```
postmeta
meta_id post_id  meta_key    meta_value

109       1       city          1
110       1       featured      h
111       2       city          1,2
112       2       featured      both
113       3       city          2,3
114       3       featured      both
115       4       city          1
116       4       featured      n
117       5       city          1,4
118       5       featured      h 
119       6       city          1
120       6       featured      h
```

I am trying to run a query that would give me a list of posts which has the following conditions:

1. Whose value against city has 1 AND
2. whose value for featured is either h or both AND
3. whose post status is Publish AND
4. whose post type is Store
5. Order them by title

The query I am trying is

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID , posts.*, postmeta.*
            FROM posts, postmeta
            WHERE posts.ID = postmeta.post_id
            AND (postmeta.meta_value  = 'h' OR postmeta.meta_value = 'both') 

AND (postmeta.meta_key = 'post_city_id' AND (postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%,1,%' OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%1,%'  OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%,1%' OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%1%'))

            AND posts.post_status = 'Publish' 
            AND posts.post_type = 'Store'

            ORDER BY (SELECT postmeta.meta_value from postmeta where (posts.ID = postmeta.post_id) and postmeta.meta_key LIKE '%home_featured_type%') asc, posts.post_title LIMIT 0,6
```

The correct returns would be IDs 1 and 2 i.e. abc and def. But I am getting empty result. I cannot figure out where it is falling apart. How can this be fixed?

Comment: order by posts.title  I have mistaken mentioned posts.post_title here in the query...it would be posts.title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a fixed query, but I still don't understand the mysterious `ORDER BY (SELECT)` thingie.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ce5a/19

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID , posts.*, postmeta_city.*, postmeta_featured.*

FROM       posts

INNER JOIN postmeta AS postmeta_city
     ON     postmeta_city.post_id = posts.ID
    AND     postmeta_city.meta_key = 'city'
    AND (   postmeta_city.meta_value LIKE '%,1,%'
         OR postmeta_city.meta_value LIKE '%1,%'
         OR postmeta_city.meta_value LIKE '%,1%'
         OR postmeta_city.meta_value LIKE '%1%'
        )
INNER JOIN postmeta AS postmeta_featured
     ON     postmeta_featured.post_id = posts.ID
    AND     postmeta_featured.meta_key = 'featured'
    AND (   postmeta_featured.meta_value = 'h'
         OR postmeta_featured.meta_value = 'both'
        )

WHERE posts.post_status = 'Publish' 
  AND posts.post_type = 'Store'

ORDER BY (
    SELECT postmeta.meta_value
    FROM postmeta
    WHERE ( posts.ID = postmeta.post_id )
      AND postmeta.meta_key LIKE '%home_featured_type%'
  ) asc,
  posts.title

LIMIT 0,6;
;
```

Updated with other people's ideas, please upvote them:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ce5a/33

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID , posts.*, postmeta_city.*, postmeta_featured.*

FROM       posts

INNER JOIN postmeta AS postmeta_city
     ON postmeta_city.post_id = posts.ID
    AND postmeta_city.meta_key = 'city'
    AND FIND_IN_SET('1', postmeta_city.meta_value)

INNER JOIN postmeta AS postmeta_featured
     ON postmeta_featured.post_id = posts.ID
    AND postmeta_featured.meta_key = 'featured'
    AND postmeta_featured.meta_value IN ('h','both')

WHERE posts.post_status = 'Publish' 
  AND posts.post_type = 'Store'

ORDER BY (
    SELECT postmeta.meta_value
    FROM postmeta
    WHERE ( posts.ID = postmeta.post_id )
      AND postmeta.meta_key LIKE '%home_featured_type%'
  ) asc,
  posts.title

LIMIT 0,6;
;
```

Comment: Wonderful. I am using the updated solution. Works perfectly. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an empty result set because you are `AND`ing the `meta_value` column so it has to equal two values at the same time which is impossible. Something like `val = '1' AND val = 'both'` will always return false and none of the rows would join. Instead, you must use an `OR` between conditions: city -> 1 and featured -> h/both.

Since the post must contain both city -> 1 and featured -> h/both (which are not across columns but across multiple rows), you'll need a `HAVING` clause in conjunction with a `GROUP BY` to ensure each post joins with two rows, satisfying both conditions... not one or the other.

Also, that is an awful lot of `LIKE`'s to check for the existance of a `1`. You can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    posts a
INNER JOIN
    postmeta b ON a.ID = b.post_id
    AND
    (
        (b.meta_key = 'city' AND FIND_IN_SET('1', b.meta_value) > 0)
        OR  
        (b.meta_key = 'featured' AND b.meta_value IN ('h', 'both'))
    )
WHERE
    a.post_status = 'Publish'
    AND a.post_type = 'Store'
GROUP BY
    a.ID
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY
    a.title
```

Comment: While I have accepted biziclop's updated solution, I thank you for the explanation. I will keep this in mind for the future. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID , posts.*, postmeta.*
            FROM posts AS p INNER JOIN postmeta AS pm
            WHERE p.ID = pm.post_id
            AND (pm.meta_value  in ('h','both') 

AND (pm.meta_key = 'city' AND 
(pm.meta_value LIKE '%,1,%' OR pm.meta_value LIKE '%1,%'  OR pm.meta_value LIKE '%,1%' OR pm.meta_value LIKE '%1%'))

            AND posts.post_status = 'Publish' 
            AND posts.post_type = 'Store'

            ORDER BY p.title LIMIT 0,6
```

Since you want order by title only, so there is no need to write any query in 'order by'  clause.